# error bound of a integration

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have a function, which is $f(x) = e^{1/x}$.
I want to calculate the error bound for the `Trapezoid Rule`, which formula is:

$$|E|\leq K\frac{(a-b)^3}{12\cdot n^2}$$

where $|f''(x)|\leq K$.
What's the value of $K$ for the above function?
If I calculated $f''(x)$ correctly, it should be:
$$f"(x) = \frac{e^{1/x}}{x^3}\left(\frac 1x + 2\right).$$

Please correct me if I'm wrong. The boundaries are $[1, 2]$.

Comment: Can you write down $|f''(x)|$ explicitly first?

Comment: @Sam Done! I've updated my question

Comment: Alright, now you have it explicitly. You want an upper bound on it's absolute value. What happens to the second derivative when $x\rightarrow 0$ and $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$?

Comment: it goes to infinite when `x -> 0`, and goes to 0 when `x-> infinite`

Comment: This is the time to consider what interval you are integrating the function over. Does it include 0? Notice btw that $e^{1/x}$ has no limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ since from the positive side, it's infinity but from the negative side it's 0

Comment: the boundaries are `[1, 2]` so `a=1` and `b=2`.

Comment: @Sam So my maxvalue of `K` is `3*e`?

Comment: Yep, it's a decreasing function (a fact that can be checked from the derivative). Just a minor point, you actually want a "min" value of $K$ since it sounds like you want to find the least upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at $f''$ you should be able to convince yourself that it is decreasing over $[1,2]$.  In that case, the maximum value is $f''(1)$, which is then $K$